# Where to download xsd about sparql protocol for rdf

Tags: rdf, w3c, sparql

I want to write web service for sparql enpoint so I need wsdl and xsd. Here: http://www.w3.org/TR/sprot11/ I read that wsdl can be download from adress http://www.w3.org/TR/sprot11/sparql-protocol-query-11.wsdl but these wsdl import xsd which doesnt exits: www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-XMLres/result2.xsd . I wrote w3c 3 days ago but still no aswer. is there some other server where I can download all xsd about sparql which I need ?

Comment: Are you trying to generate from the WSDL some code that will make HTTP calls to a SPARQL endpoint?

Comment: something like that. I need wsdl to soap ui which create soap envelope from this

Comment: Why SOAP?  I dont know of any SPARQL implementations that support SOAP.  I *strongly* recommend you just use the HTTP bindings.  Everyone supports them and there are lots of libraries you can use to make SPARQL protocol requests over HTTP; there's no need for code generation or to roll your own.

Comment: it is a request of customer so I have no choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and downloaded the wsdl that you mention in your question, but cannot find a reference to an xsd other than this one:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/sparql-protocol-query/#">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/09/sparql-protocol-types/#"
             schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/proto-wd/sparql- 
             protocol-types.xsd" />
</xs:schema>
```

The xsd in the excerpt above is available at the URL given in the `schemaLocation` attribute.

This [page on SPARQL and WSDL](http://www.w3.org/wiki/SparqlProtocolWsdl11Examples) might be helpful.